Ubuntu Server 22.04.4 LTS. /dev/mapper/vg0-lv--1 issue!
Hello I have the issue that my /dev/mapper/vg0-lv--1  gets full if I try to install something and if I run a app then it gets from 70% to 73% and at installations to 100% and it says: (ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device) But the problem is the only thing that is full is the /dev/mapper/vg0-lv--1!
Filesystem              1K-blocks       Used   Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                    26401180       3112    26398068   1% /run  
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv--1    10475520   10470432        5088 100% /
tmpfs                   132005888          0   132005888   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5120          0        5120   0% /run/lock
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv--0    10475520    3512880     6962640  34% /var
/dev/sda2                51290592     646104    48006664   2% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv--2 23349639168 7295898288 16053740880  32% /home
/dev/sda1                 1098628       6232     1092396   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                    26401176          8    26401168   1% /run/user/1000

I can record a video if that helps just let me know!
Is it possible to just mount it in a parent directory of /home?
I used this guide to setup the ubuntu server:
https://systemzone.net/ubuntu-server-20-04-installation-with-lvm/[/URL]
Thanks for any help!

did you create volume /dev/mapper/vg0-lv--1   for some specific purpose ?  if you did easiest would be to destroy then recreate it bigger ... with more effort perhaps unless it contains treasured files is to resize it  ...  just google how to resize a volume ...  no need to rehash details

No I just followed the tutorial on the website can I just delete it? Without data loose?

I am not so familar with setup ubuntu I just followed the instruction, could you tell me how to remove the hing safely I don't want to follow any instruction that destroys the os and results in data loose!    My status is noob in those things!     I would be thank full if it takes not too much time for you! And Can the devmapper from var removed too?         Thanks for any help!!!
